# Flask App Builder - override field's widget

Tags: python, flask, flask-appbuilder

Extending a `ModelView` is it possible to override a field's widget? There is option to specify the widget type for `edit_form_extra_fields` or `add_form_extra_fields`.

```
add_form_extra_fields = {
    'extra': TextField(gettext('Extra Field'),
    description=gettext('Extra Field description'),
    widget=BS3TextFieldWidget())
}
```

Similar to this is it possible to specify a mapping to change the field of non-extra fields ?

Trying to use Select2ManyWidget to render as tagged field, https://select2.org/tagging

Comment: Trying to do exactly this. Did you find a solution?